# Pushing git repo files to server

Tags: git, centos, bitbucket, centos5

I'm currently using BitBucket.org as an online collaborative Git repository for my projects. I also have a server with Git and SSH running Centos 5.9. On my Bitbucket repos, I have a "master" (production) branch, and a "development" branch.

I want to set it to to where when I merge changes into my "master" branch, these files get sent to my Centos server, and the changes are then made live on the website.

I've found these two pages online, but I'm not 100% sure if it's what I'm looking for:

- http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto
- http://sebduggan.com/blog/deploy-your-website-changes-using-git/

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should look into setting up a [post-receive hook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/POST+Service+Management) in bitbucket...

This tutorial seems to cover most of what you will need: http://brandonsummers.name/blog/2012/02/10/using-bitbucket-for-automated-deployments/

Comment: I went through the entire tutorial, and the deploy script ALMOST works. The script runs, and creates a valid `deployment.log` file with no errors, however the files on the server are never updated.

Comment: Yeah if you read the comments there are a few solutions to that. It probably has to do with the user you are running it as.

Comment: I ran "php -r "passthru('whoami');" (like suggested), but I received an error: sh: /usr/local/php/bin/whoami: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you running that from the command line? Should work, what about if you run it from within a php script? `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>`

Comment: Matt, when I run that line of code in a php file, nothing is output on the screen. I do not see any errors onscreen either. And yes, I ran the first "whoami" from the command line.

Comment: Looking around in SSH, I found `whoami` located in `/usr/bin/whoami`, and running it shows "root" in the command line, however I did not run this through PHP. How can I update this default whoami path?

Comment: Yeah thats the correct location for whoami... normally PHP would be able to find it... so it might mean that exec is not working properly on your system... or it could still just be a permissions issue... try this setup as well which is a modification of the originally linked script: https://bitbucket.org/itjgray/bitbucket-php-deploy/src/4afec57d5d00?at=master

Comment: thanks for the continued support. The link you provided me, would what only work for one directory on a web server? It looks like it will only work for a single directory (because of the defined path in git-deploy.sh). I need it to be able to work in several directories (wherever deploy-sh.php is located).

Comment: You could just provide some arguments to the bash script of which folder to work in.